# Filter a value from multiple values in a list

Tags: java

I have a list `testEle` which contains 100 elements. I am iterating over it an need to filter only the values which contains anyone of elements in second list `finalList` {a1,a2,a3...so on}

```
testEle.stream().filter( x -> x.matches(// any one of finalList element here))
```

I am not sure what should be inside the `.matches()` or if I should be using something else ?

Answer (score 1):

matches is a String function to test a regular expression on it. Just check with List::contains.

```
testEle.stream().filter( x -> finalList.contains(x))
```

Comment: Apologies but I missed mentioning that I need case insensitive comparison. So how to do that ? `finalList.contains.equalsIgnoreCase` type something

Comment: @newLearner Please [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74575570/edit) the question and include this information.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a list `testEle` which contains 100 elements. I am iterating over it an need to filter only the values which contains anyone of elements in second list `finalList`.

Since `contain()` check has a cost **O(n)** depending on the size of the `finalList` it might make sense to store its values into a `HashSet` and perform checks against the set.

```
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>(finalList);
        
testEle.stream().filter(set::contains)...
```

*From the OP's comment:*

> I need case insensitive comparison. So how to do that ? `finalList.contains.equalsIgnoreCase` type something

Then you can create a stream over the `finalList` inside the filter and apply [`Stream.anyMacth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) as a terminal operation of the nested stream.

```
List<Foo> finalList = // initializing the list
        
testEle.stream().filter(x -> 
        finalList.stream().anyMatch(y -> y.equalsIgnoreCase(x))
    )...
```